# Pynput mouse and keyboard on same program

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to run Pynput with both the keyboard and the mouse. I'm able to get the mouse to register and start/stop and exit program correctly. However, I'm struggling getting the keyboard to run correctly. ---end goal is to make it so I can run in circles and be able to turn on an auto click function. Here's the code:

```
import time
import threading

from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

delay = 0.31
keyboard_delay = 1
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char=']')
start_stop_cirlces = KeyCode(char='[')
exit_key = KeyCode(char=';')



class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    print('Welcome to the ClickMouse Auto Click Bot! \n\nCurrent delay setting for the click function is: {} seconds between clicks \n\nIn order to Start/Stop the Auto Click function- \n-Press the {} key \n\nTo exit the program- \n-Press the {} key \n\nEnjoy!\n\n\n~~Created by CrudeExistence.'.format(delay,start_stop_key,exit_key))
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)

class RunCirlces(threading.Thread):
    print('The program is running and ready to run cirlces.')
    def __init__(self, delay):
        super(RunCirlces, self).__init__()
        self.delay = keyboard_delay
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_circles(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_circles(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_circles()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                keyboard.press('w')
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                keyboard.release('w')
                keybaord.press('d')
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                keybaord.release('d')
                keybaord.press('s')
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                keyboard.release('s')
                keyboard.press('a')
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                keyboard.release('a')
            time.sleep(0.1)

keyboard = KeyboardController()
mouse = MouseController()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
cirlce_thread = RunCirlces(delay)
click_thread.start()
circle_thread.start()

def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == start_stop_cirlces:
        if circle_thread.running:
            circle_thread.stop_circles()
        else:
            circle_thread.start_circles()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AutoClickTest.py", line 85, in 
> circle_thread.start() NameError: name 'circle_thread' is not defined

However, I've named the circle_thread and assigned it. I've double checked the spelling and can't for the life of me figure out what is causing it to trip. Can anyone look over the code and help me see and understand where I messed up?

line 85 is the circle_thread.start()

The autoclicker works perfect. It's just the keyboard part that won't work and throws errors and or crashes the script.

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled it. `cirlce_thread` apparently. Check it again.

Comment: I.... have that word misspelled all throughout my code going back and forth. I'm both ashamed and laughing LOL. Well, thank you. I'm glad it was something so simple. I'll have to double check everything in the morning and see if I can get it working with those words spelled correctly